# Android convert customized alertview to a bitmap?

Tags: java, android

I want to take a image of a customized alert view.I already converted LinearLayout to a bitmap using buildDrawingCache and works fine but when I try to convert a customized alertview(uses RelativeLayout) to a bitmap it gives me an error.

//convert view to an image

```
private String getLayoutBitmap() {
        RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.glayer);
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bikeBm = view.getDrawingCache();

        File filePath = getFileStreamPath("twitterimage1.jpg");
        // delete saved image
        if (new File(filePath.toString()).delete()) {
            Log.i("INTERNAL_STORAGE_IMG_FILE", "deleted");
        }

        try {
            // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to
            // the OutputStream
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("twitterimage1.jpg",
                    Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
            bikeBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
        }
        return filePath.toString();
    }
```

//exception

```
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at com.bike.app.ScoreClass.getLayoutBitmap(ScoreClass.java:435)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at com.bike.app.ScoreClass.initShareIntent(ScoreClass.java:475)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at com.bike.app.ScoreClass.access$0(ScoreClass.java:460)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at com.bike.app.ScoreClass$2.onClick(ScoreClass.java:156)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
02-22 11:18:37.758: E/AndroidRuntime(21822):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: So you have a null pointer on line 435. Which line is that?

Comment: line 435 is RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.glayer);

Comment: Strange, there's nothing there that would usually throw an NPE. 1) Have you changed your code since you got that log? If so, get a fresh log and see if it shows a different line. 2) Was there more in logcat, or is this the full trace?

Comment: sorry for the mistake line 435 is view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Comment: Then `view` is null. Make sure the id you're using on the previous line is correct(`R.id.glayer`), and that it's in the currently set contentview.

Comment: actually no.R.id.glayer is the xml file of the customized alertview.set contentview is different with glayer.in the score class I'm displaying customized alert view.in that alertview I have a  twitter button which takes an image of alertview and send to twitter

Comment: if it's impossible to take an image of view without setting contentview is there solution to this problem?